# How do i transfer files from my AWS S3 Bucket to Public AWS S3 Presigned url using Node js?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

I have an AWS S3 Bucket with images. I need to transfer these images to a public s3 pre-signed URL which I have.

Req way: I need to utilize my AWS S3 Bucket image URL directly to send the data to the public pre-signed URL.

Another way that I am aware of is: Download the image from my AWS S3 and upload it to the s3 public pre-signed URL. But I don't want this approach.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The approach you don't want is the only one that works.

Comment: Are you saying that the only way to upload to the destination S3 bucket is via a pre-signed URL? Can they give you another way of permitting the upload?

Comment: I think i sort of figured out my way:

I can generate a pre-signed URL for my s3 object URL and then use

const body = await request(options); where the option has pre-signed URL and encoding=null as: option ={ uri:"",encoding=null} and then pass it to PUT method via fetch or Axios